# Taylor Series Graph vs Equivalent Function Graph

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion, graphing-functions

I'm sure this will be an easy question for someone with more experience. I'm just learning the Taylor series and I was told that there is an equivalent Taylor series for every polynomial, cool!

So I start out easy I graph 1/(1-x) and excuse my funky syntax, sum(x^n, n from 0 to infinity). The graphs clearly are the same for a range, but the Taylor series is missing a big chunk.

So I figure it's because I started n from 0, so I tried -infinity, but I couldn't get that to graph. Starting from a finite negative didn't help either.

What am I missing here? Keep in mind these are my baby steps in the Taylor series.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Taylor series have a radius of convergent of $R=1$

That is it approximates your function only on the interval $(-1,1)$

Do not expect any good graph outside that interval.

Comment: We haven't covered convergence yet, I guess I just discovered it. Thanks.